# How to format a numeric column as phone number in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have table in the database with a phone number column. The numbers look like this:

```
123456789
```

I want to format that to look like this:

```
123-456-789
```

Comment: Do you want to format them in SQL or your client display code (ASP, WinForms, XML, etc)?

Comment: to sql - in other words to update to the new format

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This should do it:

```
UPDATE TheTable
SET PhoneNumber = SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 1, 3) + '-' + 
                  SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 4, 3) + '-' + 
                  SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 7, 4)
```

Incorporated Kane's suggestion, you can compute the phone number's formatting at runtime.  One possible approach would be to use scalar functions for this purpose (works in SQL Server):

```
CREATE FUNCTION FormatPhoneNumber(@phoneNumber VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR(12)
BEGIN
    RETURN SUBSTRING(@phoneNumber, 1, 3) + '-' + 
           SUBSTRING(@phoneNumber, 4, 3) + '-' + 
           SUBSTRING(@phoneNumber, 7, 4)
END
```

Comment: Also if you wanted to keep the original value plus have the new formating you could add a computed column (using something similar to @David's answer above)

Comment: That should be a `RETURNS varchar(12)` and the last `SUBSTRING` needs to be `SUBSTRING(@phoneNumber, 7, 4)`

Comment: @Serj Sagan: Thanks, I've updated the code as noted.

Answer (score 18):

I'd generally recommend you leave the formatting up to your front-end code and just return the data as-is from SQL. However, to do it in SQL, I'd recommend you create a user-defined function to format it. Something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnFormatPhoneNumber](@PhoneNo VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS VARCHAR(25)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Formatted VARCHAR(25)

IF (LEN(@PhoneNo) <> 10)
    SET @Formatted = @PhoneNo
ELSE
    SET @Formatted = LEFT(@PhoneNo, 3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@PhoneNo, 4, 3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@PhoneNo, 7, 4)

RETURN @Formatted
END
GO
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
SELECT [dbo].[fnFormatPhoneNumber](PhoneNumber) AS PhoneNumber
FROM SomeTable
```

It has a safeguard in, in case the phone number stored isn't the expected number of digits long, is blank, null etc - it won't error.

**EDIT:** Just clocked on you want to update your existing data. The main bit that's relevant from my answer then is that you need to protect against "dodgy"/incomplete data (i.e. what if some existing values are only 5 characters long)

Comment: you may want to consider updating the code sample to check first to see if the length <> 10 chars since that would be the smallest valid number in this context. With a prefix it would be 11 characters. Same goes for the else statement. You want to take in the groups as 3 digits + 3 digits + 4 digits

Answer (score 14):

Above users mentioned, those solutions are very basic and they won't work if the database has different phone formats like:

```
(123)123-4564
123-456-4564
1234567989
etc
```

Here is a more complex solution that will work with ANY input given:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_FormatPhone] (@PhoneNumber VARCHAR(32))
RETURNS VARCHAR(32)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Phone CHAR(32)

    SET @Phone = @PhoneNumber

    -- cleanse phone number string
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @PhoneNumber) > 0
        SET @PhoneNumber = REPLACE(@PhoneNumber, SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @PhoneNumber), 1), '')

    -- skip foreign phones
    IF (
            SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber, 1, 1) = '1'
            OR SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber, 1, 1) = '+'
            OR SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber, 1, 1) = '0'
            )
        AND LEN(@PhoneNumber) > 11
        RETURN @Phone

    -- build US standard phone number
    SET @Phone = @PhoneNumber
    SET @PhoneNumber = '(' + SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber, 1, 3) + ') ' + SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber, 4, 3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber, 7, 4)

    IF LEN(@Phone) - 10 > 1
        SET @PhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber + ' X' + SUBSTRING(@Phone, 11, LEN(@Phone) - 10)

    RETURN @PhoneNumber
END
```

Answer (score 9):

I do not recommend keeping bad data in the database and then only correcting it on the output.  We have a database where phone numbers are entered in variously as :

- (555) 555-5555
- 555+555+5555
- 555.555.5555
- (555)555-5555
- 5555555555

Different people in an organization may write various retrieval functions and updates to the database, and therefore it would be harder to set in place formatting and retrieval rules.  I am therefore correcting the data in the database first and foremost and then setting in place rules and form validations that protect the integrity of this database going forward.

I see no justification for keeping bad data unless as suggested a duplicate column be added with corrected formatting and the original data kept around for redundancy and reference, and YES I consider badly formatted data as BAD data.

Comment: I'm not really sure whether I would consider the phone number example from the question as badly formatted.

Comment: Sometimes, especially in large organizations, the data source is outside of your control/reach and can only be corrected on the output.

Answer (score 8):

Solutions that use `SUBSTRING` and concatenation `+` are nearly independent of RDBMS. Here is a short solution that is specific to SQL Server:

```
declare @x int = 123456789
select stuff(stuff(@x, 4, 0, '-'), 8, 0, '-')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also try this:

```
CREATE  function [dbo].[fn_FormatPhone](@Phone varchar(30)) 
returns varchar(30)
As
Begin
declare @FormattedPhone varchar(30)

set     @Phone = replace(@Phone, '.', '-') --alot of entries use periods instead of dashes
set @FormattedPhone =
    Case
      When isNumeric(@Phone) = 1 Then
        case
          when len(@Phone) = 10 then '('+substring(@Phone, 1, 3)+')'+ ' ' +substring(@Phone, 4, 3)+ '-' +substring(@Phone, 7, 4)
          when len(@Phone) = 7  then substring(@Phone, 1, 3)+ '-' +substring(@Phone, 4, 4)
          else @Phone
        end
      When @phone like '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' Then '('+substring(@Phone, 1, 3)+')'+ ' ' +substring(@Phone, 5, 3)+ '-' +substring(@Phone, 8, 4)
      When @phone like '[0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' Then '('+substring(@Phone, 1, 3)+')'+ ' ' +substring(@Phone, 5, 3)+ '-' +substring(@Phone, 9, 4)
      When @phone like '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' Then '('+substring(@Phone, 1, 3)+')'+ ' ' +substring(@Phone, 5, 3)+ '-' +substring(@Phone, 9, 4)
      Else @Phone
    End
return  @FormattedPhone
```

end

use on it select

```
(SELECT [dbo].[fn_FormatPhone](f.coffphone)) as 'Phone'
```

Output will be

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use **FORMAT** if you column is a number Syntax like
FORMAT ( value, format [, culture ] ) In use like 
`FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'en-US' )` or `FORMAT(123456789,'###-##-####')` (But This works for only ***SQL SERVER 2012 And After***)

In Use Like 
`UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME = FORMAT(COLUMN_NAME ,'###-##-####')`

And

if your column is Varchar Or Nvarchar use do like this
`CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CELLPHONE,0,4),' ',SUBSTRING(CELLPHONE,4,3),'` `',SUBSTRING(CELLPHONE,7,2) ,' ',SUBSTRING(CELLPHONE,9,2) )`

You can always get help from

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: One cannot use numeric formats for phone numbers as the leading zeros are relevant!

Comment: Yes, you can.SELECT FORMAT(5553274153, '000-000-0000')

Answer (score 1):

I found that this works if wanting in a (123) - 456-7890 format.

```
UPDATE table 
SET Phone_number =  '(' +  
                    SUBSTRING(Phone_number, 1, 3) 
                    + ') ' 
                    + '- ' +
                    SUBSTRING(Phone_number, 4, 3) 
                    + '-' +
                    SUBSTRING(Phone_number, 7, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated @sqiller's function for my purposes

```
CREATE FUNCTION [toolbox].[FormatPhoneNumber] (
    @PhoneNumber VARCHAR(50),
    @DefaultIfUnknown VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- remove any extension
    IF CHARINDEX('x', @PhoneNumber, 1) > 0
        SET @PhoneNumber = SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber, 1, CHARINDEX('x', @PhoneNumber, 1) - 1)

    -- cleanse phone number string
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@PhoneNumber) > 0
        SET @PhoneNumber = REPLACE(@PhoneNumber,
                SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@PhoneNumber),1),'')

    -- Remove US international code if exists, i.e. 12345678900
    IF SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber,1,1) = '1' AND LEN(@PhoneNumber) = 11
        SET @PhoneNumber = SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber, 2, 10)

    -- any phone numbers without 10 characters are set to default
    IF LEN(@PhoneNumber) <> 10
        RETURN @DefaultIfUnknown

    -- build US standard phone number
    SET @PhoneNumber = '(' + SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber,1,3) + ') ' +
                SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber,4,3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber,7,4)

    RETURN @PhoneNumber
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just format the output no need to create a new table or a function. In this scenario the area code was on a separate fields.  I use `field1`, `field2` just to illustrate you can select other fields in the same query:

```
area  phone
213   8962102
```

Select statement:

```
Select field1, field2,areacode,phone,SUBSTR(tablename.areacode,1,3) + '-' + SUBSTR(tablename.phone,1,3) + '-' + SUBSTR(tablename.areacode,4,4) as Formatted Phone from tablename
```

Sample OUTPUT:

```
columns: FIELD1, FIELD2, AREA, PHONE, FORMATTED PHONE
data:    Field1, Field2, 213,  8962102,  213-896-2102
```