# Insert Characters into SQL string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update, substring

I have around 10,000 phone numbers all formated like:

1234567890

I need to get them like (123) 456-7890

I have tried many things already and can't seem to get my logic right, here is what I have now:

```
Update Contact
    SUBSTRING(Telephone1, 0, 0) + '(' +
    SUBSTRING(Telephone1, 1, 3) + ') ' +
    SUBSTRING(Telephone1, 4, 3) + '-' +
    SUBSTRING(Telephone1, 7, 4)
```

Any advise or help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1426487/2654498 - similar situation, could prove useful.

Comment: @NicholasV. Thanks for the redirect! I was so close... I searched but didn't find this, sorry!

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/1426487/2654498][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1426487/2654498
The answer has already been solved as @NicholasV. stated.

Comment: No worries, everyone searches differently and therefore gets different results :D Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    Num VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT @table 
VALUES ('1234567890'),  ('0987654321')


SELECT * 
FROM @table

UPDATE @table
SET Num = SUBSTRING(Num, 0, 0) + '(' +
    SUBSTRING(Num, 1, 3) + ') ' +
    SUBSTRING(Num, 4, 3) + '-' +
    SUBSTRING(Num, 7, 4)
FROM @table

SELECT * 
FROM @table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of this

```
--TO UPDATE --> USED THIS QUERY (RUN THIS ONCE ONLY)
UPDATE Contact SET Telephone1 = '(' + SUBSTRING(Telephone1, 1,3) + ') ' + SUBSTRING(Telephone1, 4,3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(Telephone1, 7,4)

--TO UPDATE WITH CHECKING --> USED THIS QUERY
UPDATE Contact SET Telephone1 = '(' + SUBSTRING(Telephone1, 1,3) + ') ' + SUBSTRING(Telephone1, 4,3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(Telephone1, 7,4)
WHERE NOT Telephone1 LIKE '(%'
        --AND NOT Telephone1 LIKE '%)'
        --AND NOT Telephone1 LIKE '%-%'

--UPDATE IS NECESSARY THEN USE QUERY LIKE THIS
SELECT  '(' + SUBSTRING(Telephone1, 1,3) + ') ' + SUBSTRING(Telephone1, 4,3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(Telephone1, 7,4) AS Telephone1
FROM    Contact
```