# Format raw varchar field to phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm helping a friend with a winforms app loaded with crystal reports (two things I generally try to avoid so pardon my ignorance).  Anyhow if I have a varchar database field:

```
2123456789
```

And want to display it on the **crystal**report as:

```
(212)-345-6789
```

How would I go about that without changing the stored procs, or the database data type (not trying to open that can of worms).  From what I've been apply to surmise if it was a numeric or int field then I would be able to use the Format Object number tab.  However this is not an option due to the datatyping.

### EDIT

My goal is Formatting the data in the crystal report or back end code of the crystal report  not the database or t-sql.  Thanks

Comment: The data typing is exactly right. It definitely shouldn't be a numeric type

Comment: @podiluska Not really my question, but my experience is that int column takes up less bytes and is also more perfomant if someone want's to do a phone number search against a table with half a billion records in it.  But again I just need to format it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426487/format-phone-number)

Comment: Do not make a phone number field an int.  Its not an int, its a string.

Comment: @paqogomez I am trying to format the field at crystal report layer.  I am in no way attempting to alter the database or the sql.

Comment: @paqogomez I am not asking how to format a phone number in t-sql.  I am asking how to format a phone number in crystal reports, if you would be so kind as to not mark the question as a duplicate as it is not, thankyou

Comment: Ok, I retracted the duplicate.  Would this, the first google hit, [be more helpful?](http://www.paulhobson.com/wordpress/2009/07/formatting-phone-numbers-in-crystal-reports/)

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna Your experience is wrong. Phone numbers can and do begin with a zero.

Comment: Not in this country !  Zip codes thank you NJ are a different story

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the field's display-string formula to:

```
Picture(CurrentFieldValue,"(XXX) XXX-XXXX")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Mid("2123456789",1,3)+" - "+Mid("2123456789",4,3)+" - "+ Mid("2123456789",7,4)
```

Comment: pardon my ignorance but what am I doing with that ?

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna didn't is this msg for me?