# Format phone number to international

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, format, substring, vtiger

I already found "[How to format a numeric column as phone number in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426487/format-phone-number)" but it just destroyed my number.

I have a phone number like `064184335` and want to format it to `+49 641 84335`.

I tried:

```
UPDATE vtiger_contactdetails
    SET phone = '+49' +' '+ SUBSTRING(phone, 2, 2 ) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(phone, 4, 3)
```

but I  got `295` as phonenumber.
Also the `3` in the second `SUBSTRING` should be the rest of the phone number.

If I want to change every phone number in different tables shouldn't it work with:

```
UPDATE vtiger_account, vtiger_contactdetails, vtiger_contactsubdetails
SET vtiger_account.phone = CONCAT('+49', ' ', SUBSTRING(vtiger_account.phone, 2, 3 ), ' ', SUBSTRING(vtiger_account.phone, 5, length(vtiger_account.phone)))
SET vtiger_account.otherphone = CONCAT('+49', ' ', SUBSTRING(vtiger_account.otherphone, 2, 3 ), ' ', SUBSTRING(vtiger_account.otherphone, 5, length(vtiger_account.otherphone)))
SET vtiger_contactdetails.phone = CONCAT('+49', ' ', SUBSTRING(vtiger_contactdetails.phone, 2, 3 ), ' ', SUBSTRING(vtiger_contactdetails.phone, 5, length(vtiger_contactdetails.phone)))
SET vtiger_contactdetails.mobile = CONCAT('+49', ' ', SUBSTRING(vtiger_contactdetails.mobile, 2, 3 ), ' ', SUBSTRING(vtiger_contactdetails.mobile, 5, length(vtiger_contactdetails.mobile)))
SET vtiger_contactsubdetails.homephone = CONCAT('+49', ' ', SUBSTRING(vtiger_contactsubdetails.homephone, 2, 3 ), ' ', SUBSTRING(vtiger_contactsubdetails.homephone, 5, length(vtiger_contactsubdetails.homephone)))
SET vtiger_contactsubdetails.otherphone = CONCAT('+49', ' ', SUBSTRING(vtiger_contactsubdetails.otherphone, 2, 3 ), ' ', SUBSTRING(vtiger_contactsubdetails.otherphone, 5, length(vtiger_contactsubdetails.otherphone)))
SET vtiger_contactsubdetails.assistantphone = CONCAT('+49', ' ', SUBSTRING( vtiger_contactsubdetails.assistantphone, 2, 3 ), ' ', SUBSTRING( vtiger_contactsubdetails.assistantphone, 5, length( vtiger_contactsubdetails.assistantphone)))
```

How do I ignore already formatted numbers?

Comment: I'd actually store the country code (`'+49'`) in another column, as you wouldn't need it if calling _within_ that country.  For that matter, you shouldn't store it formatted either - that's a display-layer issue.

Comment: for my second code I just get a syntax error. Im new to this stuff. I'll try my best, please don't judge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using MySQL.  The way to concatenate strings is `concat()`:

```
UPDATE vtiger_contactdetails
    SET phone = CONCAT('+49', ' ', SUBSTRING(phone, 2, 2 ), ' ', SUBSTRING(phone, 4, 3));
```

To get all the characters, just use two arguments to `SUBSTRING()`:

```
UPDATE vtiger_contactdetails
    SET phone = CONCAT('+49', ' ', SUBSTRING(phone, 2, 2 ), ' ', SUBSTRING(phone, 4));
```

Note that this works in MySQL, but not in all databases.

Comment: okay thanks its working at first. But is there a way to change the second Substring so it adds the left numbers until the end?

Comment: You can use `substring(phone, 4, length(phone))`.  The length argument is too big, but that is ok.  `substring()` stops at the end of the string.  Or, just use two arguments.

Comment: its working fine thanks. but how can I ignore already formated numbers? I tried WHERE phone NOT LIKE '+49 ____' but it didnt work

Comment: Use a regular expressions (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) if you want to specify all the spacing an numbers.  Otherwise, `where phone not like '+49 %'` may do a good enough job.

Answer (score 0):

Try the modified query:

```
SELECT '+49' +' '+ SUBSTRING('064184335', 2, 3 ) + ' ' 
    + SUBSTRING('064184335' , 5, 5)
```

Update using just `+`:

```
  UPDATE vtiger_contactdetails
    SET phone = '+49' +' '+ SUBSTRING(phone, 2, 3 ) + ' ' 
        + SUBSTRING(phone , 5, 5)
```

Using `CONCAT`:

```
UPDATE vtiger_contactdetails
    SET phone = CONCAT('+49', ' ', 
    SUBSTRING(phone, 2, 3 ), ' ', SUBSTRING(phone, 5, 5))
```

Comment: its always a different number and i want to select all to format them all at once

Comment: First one is just an examble. try the other two also.

Comment: using concat works fine for me. thanks i just need to try updating several tables and numbers at once. ill try myself first