# Change Phone format

Tags: sql

In an SQL table I have the phone value: 817-683-1691 and I need to transform it to: (817) 683-1691

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: OK. Awesome.  1) what db?, 2)what have you tried?  Please read [ask] and post a [mcve]

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: sql  server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use substring function. Also, this is a dupe: [How to format a numeric column as phone number in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426487/how-to-format-a-numeric-column-as-phone-number-in-sql). This topic converts from 999999999 to 999-99-9999 which you already have. But the solution is the same. Basically you want to add the substring of "()" to the first LEFT 3 char